# Is there a mathematical function to calculate f?

Tags: java, math

I got this code from a coworker and I need to find out how big f would be at the end. I tried running it but it didn't finish after several hours. Is there a mathematical function/expression to solve this?

One approach I have is using Sum-notations, but I can't seem to figure out how to calculate the sum's bounds.

```
private long f(){
    long a = 1;
    long f = a;
    for (long i = 0; i < a ; i++){
        f++;
        long b = f;
        
        for (long k = 0; k < b ; k++){
            f++;
            long c = f;

            for (long j = 0; j < c ; j++){
                f++;
                long d = f;

                for (long m = 0; m < d ; m++){
                    f++;
                    long e = f;
                    
                    for (long n = 0; n < e ; n++){
                        f++;
                        long h = f;

                        for (long p = 0; p < h ; p++){
                            f = f+4;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
return f;
}
```

Comment: I think you're being trolled. Even if you wrote this out mathematically, it would not resemble any normal summation: `f` becomes negative due to overflow and (unlike many other cases) that makes a qualitative difference (not just "apply modulo at the end") since the resulting negative bound makes some loops run 0 iterations after a while.

Comment: You can do some transformation of the inner loop to make the code run to completion in reasonable time.. You'd have to be a bit careful, the effect of that loop is *not* `f += 4 * h` (negative `h` does not make the loop run a negative number of times)

Comment: You could use [sum of series](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/sum-of-the-first-n-terms-of-a-series) equations to get rid of the loops ... however as harold mentioned you will soon hit integer overflow causing some numbers to be negative ... so its hard to say if there is a possibility of the loops ending on used bitwidth